# Assigning a Variable the Identity of Another

Tags: java, pass-by-reference, identity

I have an Item class. Each Item object is held in an instance of the ItemNode class. ItemNode is an inner class in my CustomList class.

My Item class has an attribute named amount. This refers to how many of that type of Item are owned by the user

My ItemNode class also has an attribute named amount. I want the ItemNode's amount attribute to always equal the amount attribute of the Item object it holds.

In other words, `(ItemNode.amount == ItemNode.item.amount)`, should always be true, even if I change the value of `itemNode.amount` later on.

How can I make Java have the same identity for both `ItemNode.amount` and `Item.amount`?

**My ItemNode Class:**

```
/**
 * Creates nodes to hold Item objects.
 */
private class ItemNode {
   // the object being held by the node
   private Item item;
   // The type of the object
   private String typeName;
   // How many are owned by the player
   private int amount;
   // What the item-subclass's name is
   private String itemName;
   // the node after this
   private ItemNode next;

   ItemNode(Item item) {

      this.data = item;
      this.typeName = typeName;
      this.itemName = item.getItemName();
      this.amount = item.getAmount();
      this.next = null;
   }
}
```

Comment: 1) ***DON'T*** give ItemNode an amount field. Instead simply have your `getAmount()` method from ItemNode return the value from the item it holds. Nothing more, nothing less. The Decorator design pattern may be what you're looking for.

Comment: But that won't let me change `ItemNode.amount` and `Item.amount` at the same time.

Comment: That's because you **shouldn't** be changing both, nor should you have both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't give your ItemNode class an amount field as by doing this you're creating "parallel fields" and must take pains to make sure that they stay in sync, when in fact they can fall out of sync easily. Instead and much more simply give your ItemNode class a public `getAmount()` method that simply calls and returns its item's `getAmount()` method. Same if you need setter methods. Remember to make your code as idiot-proof as possible. Also look into the Decorator design pattern as this problem seems to be partially solved by this.

```
public interface Amountable {

    int getAmount();

    void setAmount(int amount);

}
```

```
public class Item implements Amountable {
    private int amount;

    public Item(int amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    @Override
    public int getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAmount(int amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

}
```

```
public class ItemNode<T extends Amountable> implements Amountable {
    private T item;

    public ItemNode(T item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    @Override
    public int getAmount() {
        return item.getAmount();
    }

    @Override
    public void setAmount(int amount) {
        item.setAmount(amount);
    }    

    public T getItem() {
        return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: GM Mr Eels. Unrelated question: I see that your activity profile shows 61K "votes cast". Just wondering: my understanding is that this number shows all votes that were cast ... on content that wasnt deleted. Now I am curious how you ever got to that number? I did a lot of close reviews (from the queue) the other week, but it seems that many of these items get later ... closed, and deleted. And therefore that counter is growing like really slowly. In other words: do you have some specific "pattern"?